# Applications menu in 11.04=> how to add a search/run box?

Tags: 11.04, appmenu

Some other time I had another Linux installation that had this neat & active search/run box in the main Applications menu.
That is missing in my current installation of 11.04.

Would someone teach me how to get one of those please ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deskbar-Applet appears in my 'add to' choices and it does enough that I consider this question answered well enough - thanks for the info folks !!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean the SUSE main menu, which looked like this:

[image: SUSE Main Menu]

It is no longer maintained, as far as I know, and it definitely won't work with the GNOME 3.x gnome-panel. However, you can get the source from http://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-main-menu and attempt to use it, if you wish.

Comment: 11.04 still uses gnome 2

Comment: Yes. And it also EOLs in 6 months, and gnome-main-menu is still basically unmaintained. Probably better to upgrade sooner rather than later. 11.10 and 12.04 have gnome-panel 3.x. So it's pertinent information, as if one does make it work on 11.04, it will stop working after upgrading.

Comment: perhaps consider adding the mint menu applet for gnome 2 in your answer?

Comment: I use the Cardapio menu, which I really like.  It has a very nice search box that makes it unnecessary to use the mouse in most cases (even to bring up the menu).  If I want to run a program, I press the hotkey (Win-space, but configurable), type a couple of characters, then press return.  But if you want to use the mouse, it's nicely organized, with pinned items and categories.

Comment: @UriHerrera I have no idea what the mint menu applet is or was. But again, if it was written for GNOME 2.x and doesn't support 3.x, it will have the same problems on upgrade.

Comment: After reading Marty's comment here I found this: [link] http://www.webupd8.org/2011/09/cardapio-menu-gets-gnome-shell.html - is this the best way to try it, or is there a better method, please ? (@Marty Fried - Thanks !!!)

Comment: Tried installing Cardapio and it failed with errors when I used the commands posted at that site...boohoo.

Comment: @mark Ubuntu 11.04 does not have GNOME 3.x (gnomel-shell), which that link is about. I think you'd have to install an older version of Cardapio to have it work on 11.04.